# What windows or coverings provide privacy but allow natural light in?

Tags: bathroom, windows

### Objective

What windows can obscure a silhouette while still allowing light in?

### Background

I am doing a bathroom remodel,

- Currently there is a large window in the middle of the place where I intend to have a walk-in shower. Which I would like to keep because I love natural light.
- The window is towards the street, so I need good
  privacy too.
- I've gone to Home Depot, and seen the "privacy glass" - it's not very private at all. You can still easily see the silhouette of the person showering.

Please recommend ways to have better privacy, while keeping the window.

Answer (score 1):

There are some pretty good imitation stained glass window overlays, which I think would overcome your "looks cheap" concern while *being* fairly cheap (under $30, if I remember correctly).

(I used a frosted overlay for the lower glass, only, of my downstairs bathroom since without a ladder nobody's going to be able to get line of sight above that line to any normal-height human. Leaving the top clear means more natural light. And unless someone was actively backlighting themselves, there really is zero risk of a silhouette being visible.)

Answer (score 0):

To provide privacy to guests showering while maintaining natural light, try the following:

### Stained glass

Most expensive option and will modify the color of natural light entering. This will however solve your issue of privacy.

### Frosted glass

Will obscure a clear view of a nude individual but may still show a silhouette.

### Frosted privacy film

Inexpensive. Easy to install. May still show a silhouette. It may be possible (but not recommended) to do multiple layers to further obscure the view.

### Colored tint

Will obscure the view in but will reduce the amount of natural sunlight entering the restroom area.

### 3D pattern static film

Very inexpensive around $10. The 3D patterns may help to further obscure the view in. The material being just static film is easy to apply and remove. Natural light will still be allowed in.